# C++ Program Crashes Due To Large Array Even Though It's On The Heap

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, crash, heap-memory

I'm allocating memory for three very large arrays (N = 990000001). I know you have to allocate this on the heap because it's so large, but even when I do that, the program keeps crashing. Am I allocating it incorrectly or is my computer simply not have enough memory (I should have plenty)? The other thing that may be the problem is that I'm somehow allocating my memory incorrectly. The way I'm allocating memory right now works perfectly fine when N is small. Any help is appreciated.

```
int main()
{
double *Ue = new double[N];
double *U = new double[N];
double *X = new double[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    X[i] = X0 + dx*i;
    Ue[i] = U0/pow((X0*X[i]),alpha);
}

//Declare Variables
double K1;double K2; double K3; double K4;

//Set Initial Condition
U[0] = U0;
for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
{
    K1 = deriv(U[i],X[i]);
    K2 = deriv(U[i]+0.5*dx*K1,X[i]+0.5*dx);
    K3 = deriv(U[i]+0.5*dx*K2,X[i]+0.5*dx);
    K4 = deriv(U[i]+dx*K3,X[i+1]);
    U[i+1] = U[i] + dx/6*(K1 + 2*K2 + 2*K3 + K4);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does the program crash?  If you don't tell us why...

Comment: Clarification: `990000001` == `990,000,001`

Comment: Also: what compiler/runtime do you use?

Comment: `8 bytes * 3 * 990000001 = 22.13GB`. Likely it's throwing a `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: is this compiling atleast?

Comment: One array of this size consumes almost 8GB of memory, and you are trying to allocate 3 of them. Probably you are running out of memory.

Comment: double ~ 8bytes, 990000001*8bytes*3/1024^3 ~ 22GB

Comment: I get the following error: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information. Process returned 3." I'm using Codeblocks.

Comment: @DanielFleischman: `new` shouldn't return `NULL` unless you override it.

Comment: So a double generally uses 8 bytes, and you have 990 million doubles per array?  There's no way you have over 22GB of memory in a standard PC computer.

Comment: Shove a `try { allocations } catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) { std::cout << "OOM\n"; }` around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program allocates and uses about 24 GB of memory.

If you are the program as a 32-bit process, this will throw `std::bad_alloc`, and your program will exit gracefully.  (*Theoretically* there could be an overflow bug in your toolchain, but I think this is unlikely.)

If you are the program as a 64-bit process, you might get snagged by the OOM killer and your program will exit ungracefully.  Unless you have 24 GB in combined RAM + swap, then you might churn through at the speed of your disk.  (If you *actually have* 24 GB of RAM, then it probably wouldn't crash, so we can rule this out.)  If overcommit is disabled then you will get `std::bad_alloc` instead of the OOM killer.  (This paragraph is kind of Linux-specific, though other kernels are similar.)

**Solution:** Use less memory or buy more RAM.

Comment: I have 16 GB of RAM, but I was going under the assumption that the computer would start using swap memory on the disk and get the job done (albeit slower). Poor assumption on my part.

Comment: from what i leared, its 4GB for a program in a 32-bit operating system. but if your OS is 64-bit then this should be a problem with the RAM or SWAP space. try increasing the SWAP in the latter case.

Comment: @user1562781: It depends on how your machine is configured.  I don't know the details of the Windows memory system.  On Linux, run `/sbin/swapon -s` or `cat /proc/swaps` to see a list of swap partitions.  I think these give sizes measured in 512-byte units, so the size should be well above 16 million in order for your program to run (because 16 million * 512B + 16 GB = 24 GB).

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows, you may find useful this information [Memory Limits for Applications on Windows](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memory-limits-applications-windows) -

> Note that the limit on static and stack data is the same in both
> 32-bit and 64-bit variants.  This is due to the format of the Windows
> Portable Executable (PE) file type, which is used to describe EXEs and
> DLLs as laid out by the linker. It has 32-bit fields for image section
> offsets and lengths and was not extended for 64-bit variants of
> Windows. As on 32-bit Windows, static data and stack share the same
> first 2GB of address space.

Then, the only real improvements -

> Dynamic data - this is memory that is allocated during program
> execution.  In or C or C++ this is usually done with `malloc` or `new`.
>
> 64-bit
>
> - Static data 2Gb
> - Dynamic data 8Tb
> - Stack data 1GB
>   (the stack size is set by the linker, the default is 1MB.  This can be
>   increased using the Linker property System > Stack Reserve Size)

Allocation of single array "should be able to allocate as large as the OS is willing to handle" (i.e. limited by RAM and fragmentation).